# iCloud Drive not syncing – Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/<me>

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, permission

I updated my iMac (2014, 5k) to Big Sur and after a day iCloud Drive and a bunch of other things broke. I since completely wiped my computer and I am on a fresh install. iCloud Drive still does not work. It does not show the little spinner thingy in Finder. All other iCloud based services and even third party apps seem to sync fine.

Interestingly the size of my home folder continues to grow. In Activity Monitor/Network however bird is shown with 0 bytes and cloudd is shown with some data received—growing way less than the size of the home folder however. Upon further investigation the size seems to be from Messages and Photos mostly.

iCloud Drive works fine between all my other devices—including a MacBook Pro on Big Sur.

This is an excerpt of all Console Errors and Faults containing `bird`.

```
error   15:34:58.401036+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:34:59.070728+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:35:01.733540+0100    cloudd  nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:35:01.735135+0100    cloudd  nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C41.1 IPv6#66c53e3f.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:35:01.741322+0100    cloudd  nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:35:01.742459+0100    cloudd  nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C42.1 IPv6#66c53e3f.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:35:02.429408+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:35:02.437522+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C450.1 IPv6#7e8c8767.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:35:03.404908+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:03.743549+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:35:08.440572+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:12.562387+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:35:13.525777+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:14.033143+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:35:15.326668+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:35:15.426924+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C451.1 IPv6#7e8c8767.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:35:16.416382+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:35:18.532704+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:28.795715+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:34.901609+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:35:39.676649+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:36:17.683173+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
```

#### EDIT:

Some more log messages after turning iCloud Drive off and on again

```
error   15:48:54.771724+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/hans/.DS_BarrierSync
error   15:48:54.890625+0100    kernel  System Policy: bird(983) deny(1) file-write-unlink /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session
error   15:48:54.891125+0100    bird    [ERROR] renameat(-1, '<private>', -1, '<private>', 0) failed after trying to fix permissions [1: Operation not permitted]
error   15:48:54.891213+0100    bird    [ERROR] renameat(-1, '<private>', -1, '<private>' deviceID:16777224 fileID:12884958468 mode:drwxr-xr-x nlink:10 uid:501 gid:20 atime:1605882686 mtime:1605878610 ctime:1605878610 size:320 flags:0x0 failed [1: Operation not permitted]
error   15:49:23.123805+0100    bird    [ERROR] failed stating '<private>' [2: No such file or directory]
error   15:49:23.123915+0100    bird    [ERROR] -[BRCAccountSession(BRCDatabaseManager) _stepBackupDetector:newState:error:]: (passed to caller) error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSDescription=No such file or directory}
error   15:49:23.125529+0100    bird    [ERROR] Failed to open account session: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSDescription=No such file or directory}
error   15:49:27.076534+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/client.db-wal
error   15:49:27.076596+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 23 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.076643+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/client.db-shm
error   15:49:27.076658+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 9 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.076699+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/server.db
error   15:49:27.076711+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 22 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.076761+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/server.db-wal
error   15:49:27.076800+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 24 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.076917+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/server.db-shm
error   15:49:27.076952+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 6 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.083545+0100    bird    BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/client.db
error   15:49:27.083585+0100    bird    invalidated open fd: 21 (0x11)
error   15:49:27.553966+0100    kernel  System Policy: bird(983) deny(1) file-write-unlink /Users/hans/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session
error   15:49:27.554032+0100    bird    [ERROR] Can't delete <private>: Operation not permitted(1)
error   15:49:27.572336+0100    bird    [ERROR] Can't delete <private>: No such file or directory(2)
error   15:49:27.700424+0100    bird    [ERROR] Can't delete <private>: No such file or directory(2)
error   15:49:28.210998+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C480.1 IPv6#7717b0ba.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:49:28.336941+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:49:28.556127+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because state of documentScopePublic changed - <private>
error   15:49:28.850416+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:49:29.280884+0100    nsurlsessiond   nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:49:29.716806+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:49:29.896091+0100    bird    [ERROR] can't create zone or register pushes: Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=15 UserInfo={ContainerID=<private>, NSDebugDescription=<private>, RequestUUID=<private>, errorKey=<private>, ServerErrorDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc2b3e17c50 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=6000 UserInfo={ContainerID=<private>, RequestUUID=<private>, errorKey=<private>, ServerErrorDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc2b3e3f030 {Error Domain=CloudDocsServerExtension Code=4 UserInfo={ServerErrorDescription=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}}}}}
error   15:49:29.916906+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because cross-zone move - <private>
error   15:49:34.390858+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because state of documentScopePublic changed - <private>
error   15:49:36.250248+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because state of documentScopePublic changed - <private>
error   15:49:36.954363+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because state of documentScopePublic changed - <private>
error   15:49:38.659471+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because state of documentScopePublic changed - <private>
error   15:49:42.089708+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/hans/.DS_BarrierSync
error   15:49:42.163464+0100    bird    [ERROR] the root is closed!
  root: <private>
  self: <private>
error   15:49:42.168747+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.169217+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.169590+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.170279+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.170977+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.171529+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.172108+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.172785+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.173062+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.173696+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.174316+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.174880+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.175390+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.176141+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.176430+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.176702+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.176980+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.177206+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.177474+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.177618+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.177738+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.177907+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.178076+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.178194+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.178417+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.178550+0100    bird    [ERROR] Container needs deep-scan because creating a new stream - <private>
error   15:49:42.415508+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:49:43.051105+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:49:48.116735+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:49:54.088954+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist
error   15:49:54.548248+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
error   15:49:54.717410+0100    cloudd  nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (com.apple.bird) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.
error   15:49:54.755508+0100    cloudd  nw_endpoint_flow_validate_delegation [C111.1 IPv6#66c53e3f.443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en1, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] Network Delegation Failure: Invalid Bundle ID "com.apple.bird" [M]
error   15:49:59.558965+0100    kernel  Sandbox: bird(983) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/hans
```

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I never got it to work. I stopped using the imac eventually. Even completely wiping the iMac multiple times did not help.